# ORA-01843: not a valid month in Java application

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

We have a Java Web application deployed in SAP Netweaver that accesses an Oracle 10g Database through plain JDBC. The application was working fine until a few days ago, when a query was causing the following error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

The query that's giving us trouble is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   (SELECT inspeccion.sociedad_id,
                       inspeccion_id,
                       estado_id,
                       (SELECT des_estado
                        FROM   estado
                        WHERE  estado.estado_id = inspeccion.estado_id)
                       des_estado,
                       (SELECT numero_secuencia
                        FROM   estado
                        WHERE  estado.estado_id = inspeccion.estado_id)
                       numero_secuencia,
                       planta_id,
                       (SELECT des_planta
                        FROM   planta
                        WHERE  planta.planta_id = inspeccion.planta_id)
                       des_planta,
                       area_id,
                       (SELECT des_area
                        FROM   area
                        WHERE  area.area_id = inspeccion.area_id)       des_area
                       ,
                       igp_id,
                       '-'
                       nom_lider,
                       nom_inspector,
                       nom_responsable,
                       To_char(fecha_inspeccion, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                       fecha_inspeccion,
                       observacion,
                       recomendacion
                FROM   inspeccion) inspeccion) t_inspeccion
WHERE  estado_id NOT IN ( 10 )
       AND t_inspeccion.estado_id IN ( 11, 12 )
       AND t_inspeccion.planta_id = 42
       AND t_inspeccion.fecha_inspeccion >= To_date('01/11/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
       AND t_inspeccion.sociedad_id = '0101'
ORDER  BY t_inspeccion.numero_secuencia,
          t_inspeccion.fecha_inspeccion
```

We were suspecting of the `To_date('01/11/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` statement, but when we run the query trough DBVisualizer we have no trouble at all.

I'm kind of lost here. Maybe there's a DB Setting that's messing with the query, or some SAP Netweaver configuration? Or perhaps some Oracle Driver issue?

Comment: What data type is `fecha_inspeccion`?  Is `inspeccion` a table or a view?

Comment: Inspeccion is a table and fecha_inspeccion has a DATE data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the nested select that becomes `t_inspeccion` you have:

```
To_char(fecha_inspeccion, 'DD/MM/YYYY') fecha_inspeccion,
```

... and then in the outer `where` clause you have:

```
AND t_inspeccion.fecha_inspeccion >= To_date('01/11/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Assuming the original `inspection.fecha_inspeccion` is a `date`, you seem to be converting to to a string, then doing an implicit conversion back to a date to compare it to your fixed value. I suspect the implicit conversion of `t_inspeccion.fecha_inspeccion` is throwing the error, possibly from an unexpected `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting; which in Java is normally obtained from your locale. From the error I'd guess it's implicitly using MM/DD/YYYY, but could easily be something else.

I don't see why you had the `to_char()` at all though, unless you particularly want the text format in the results; in which case you need to either explicitly convert the date back in the `where` clause:

```
AND To_date(t_inspeccion.fecha_inspeccion, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    >= To_date('01/11/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

... or pull the original date column as well and compare using that; though that would perhaps need you to list all the other columns in the outermost `select`. If you are, or expect to be, using an index on `fecha_inspeccion` then you may also be degrading performance by treating it as a string.

Comment: Even though I explicitly alter NLS_DATE_FORMAT my oracle function return this error. At last I copied some oracle registries from a running machine to that one. Seems worked till now. Hoping not to encounter again.

Comment: My last trial mentioned above was unsuccessful. I discovered that my Java program recovers Oracle session and new session doesn't have my NLS_DATE_FORMAT attribute. Now, I'm re-altering NLS_DATE_FORMAT. God help us !

Comment: @DavutGürbüz - you should avoid relying on NLS_DATE_FORMAT at all. Why not just specify an explicit format mask whenever you need to convert between a date anda string? And use a native date wherever possible, and for as long as possible.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just call an Oracle function in `java` code .  Actually in this function there is `sysdate` inserting a table.  Error returns from this function. Although I test this function with `PL-SQL developer` and it works  perfectly java call fails.  PC regional setting is USA and I can't change it for some reason. DB uses Turkish. `dd.mm.YYYY` but US uses `mm.dd.YYYY`. I can't define explicit mask for a function call.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz - then it's the function that needs to be fixed. Presumably it's doing an implicit conversion between a string and a date (e.g. `to_date(sysdate)` which is a surprisingly common mistake). If you can't figure out where it is going wrong then please ask a new question, and include your function code.

Comment: Dear @AlexPoole , thanks for your interest to my case. The function code is more than 1000 line and this function use other functions. If I commit this function many other functions would become invalid. So, this was my best practical solution. I'm bound to an `Oracle Forms` system. Unfortunately most of the things were embedded in `oracle packages`. I don't want to take things invalid in a system which has 1000 active users. But I'll keep your suggestions on my mind.